# pass a function name defined in a library as function pointer in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

I want to develop a library in which different algorithm are defined and a function handler which can get name of one of a function in which the algorithm is defined and call it.
this is the source file (`imp_GE_s.c`):

```
#include "imp_GE_s.h"

// This is a function handler developed to get name of a functions as 
// function pointer and call the desired function 
double func_handler(void (*func)(float*, float*, float*), float* A, float* L, float* U)
{
   // call the function and do sth
}


// non-blocked KJI form of GE with column pivoting 
void LU_kij_nonBlocked(float* A, float* L, float* U)
{
   //some statements
}


// non_blocked JKI form of GE with column pivoting 
void LU_kji_nonBlocked(float* A, float* L, float* U)
{
   //some statements
}
```

and this is header file (`imp_GE_s.h`):

```
#ifndef IMP_GE_S
 #define IMP_GE_S

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <time.h>

  void LU_kij_nonBlocked(float* A, float* L, float* U);
  void LU_kji_nonBlocked(float* A, float* L, float* U);
  double func_handler(void (*func)(float*, float*, float*), float* A, float* L, float* U);

#endif
```

and this is the `main.c` file:

```
#include "imp_GE_s.h"

int main()
{
   float A[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{3,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9}};
   float L[4][4] = {0};
   float U[4][4] = {0};

   printf ("time of operation = %d \n",   func_handler((*LU_kij_nonBlocked),A,L,U));
}
```

but everytime I complile the main file by this command `gcc main.c -o main` I got the following error

`in function 'main':
example_GE_s.c:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to 'LU_kij_nonBlocked'
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: example_GE_s.c:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to 'func_handler'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: How do you think imp_GE_s.c gets compiled?

Comment: Unrelated tip: `typedef` your function-pointer-types for readability's sake.

Comment: The best solution is to get an IDE, include all files in there and let it worry about the linking. Command line linking, make files etc are things of the past.

Comment: The question is titled "flying solo around the world"  and the gist of the question is "how do I start the plane"

Answer (score 1):

There are a host of warnings you should watch out e.g. *control reaches end of non-void function*. Anyway, your issue stems from not linking the source C file(s). You need to compile like the following,

```
gcc main.c imp_GE_s.c -o exec
```

As a side note, as [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) and other C gurus say, **treat warnings as errors**.

Answer (score 0):

### Main File I named CanRemove2.c

```
#include "CanRemove333.h"

int main()
{
   float A[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{3,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9}};
   float L[4][4] = {0};
   float U[4][4] = {0};

   printf ("time of operation = %lf \n",   func_handler((*LU_kij_nonBlocked),(float**)A,(float**)L,(float**)U));
}
```

In fact when you use. Must using like below,i dont see you ask more about cast (float**),but it will be question

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    float A[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{3,4,6,8},{2,5,7,9}};
    float L[4][4] = {0};
    float U[4][4] = {0};
    float **AA=(float**)malloc(sizeof(float*)*4);
    float **LL=(float**)malloc(sizeof(float*)*4);
    float **UU=(float**)malloc(sizeof(float*)*4);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        AA[i]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*4);
        LL[i]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*4);
        UU[i]=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*4);
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            AA[i][j]=A[i][j];
            LL[i][j]=L[i][j];
            UU[i][j]=U[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf ("time of operation = %lf \n",   func_handler((*LU_kij_nonBlocked),AA,LL,UU));

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        free(AA[i]);
        free(LL[i]);
        free(UU[i]);
    }
    free(AA);
    free(LL);
    free(UU);
}
```

### imp_GE_s.h I named CanRemove333.h

```
#ifndef IMP_GE_S
 #define IMP_GE_S

  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <time.h>

  void LU_kij_nonBlocked(float** , float** , float** );
  void LU_kji_nonBlocked(float** , float** , float** );
  double func_handler(void (*)(float**, float**, float**), float** , float** , float** );

#endif
```

### imp_GE_s.c I named CanRemove333.c

```
#include "CanRemove333.h"

// This is a function handler developed to get name of a functions as 
// function pointer and call the desired function 
double func_handler(void (*func)(float**, float**, float**), float** A, float** L, float** U)
{
   // call the function and do sth
    return 1.0;
}


// non-blocked KJI form of GE with column pivoting 
void LU_kij_nonBlocked(float** A, float** L, float** U)
{
   //some statements
}


// non_blocked JKI form of GE with column pivoting 
void LU_kji_nonBlocked(float** A, float** L, float** U)
{
   //some statements
}
```

---

gcc CanRemove2.c CanRemove333.c -o Rmmm

./Rmmm

Result time of operation = 1.000000